# javascript reverse string algorithm

Tags: javascript, reverse

I'm tying to solve how to reverse a string. I already figured out how to reverse an array so i'm trying to use that answer in this one.  I figure I can convert the string to an array an then just go from there...Well this is what I have so far and tips or advice is welcome.

```
function reverse(string){
    var x = string.split(' ');
    for(i=0; i=x.length; i++){
        var y= x.pop();
        console.log(y);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would start off by learning how to indent your code, both for yourself and others looking at it. Anyway, what is the difference exactly between googling for an algorithm and asking for one on Stack Overflow? By the way, are you sure your `for` statement condition is correct?

Comment: 'Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see [ask] & [mcve]'`.split(' ').reverse().join(' ')`

Comment: The code in the question would reverse the words (separated by a space) in a string, not the letters, is that correct

Comment: You need to split the string twice, reverse the array then join them back together. And your for loop is wrong. It should be i < x.length

Comment: Remember that `pop` will change the length of the array, affecting the condition in the `for` loop (assuming it was written correctly with `<` instead of `=`).

Comment: First result in google: https://medium.freecodecamp.com/how-to-reverse-a-string-in-javascript-in-3-different-ways-75e4763c68cb#.pn7risq43

Comment: When presenting code--I assume you are posting because your code does not work as desired--explain **what it is doing that is wrong**. For instance, "it goes into an infinite loop", "it only prints every other character", etc.

Answer (score 2):

See the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/1wknqn2d/1/

```
function reverse(string){
    return string.split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

Comment: I also found the build in function is actually best performance in large string (> 64 byte)... I also want to know why?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function reverse(string){
var y =[];
var x = string.split('');
for(i=x.length-1; i>=0; i--){
    y.push(x[i]);
}
console.log(y.join(''));
}
```

or simply

```
string.split('').reverse().join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the straightforward answer that Ash gave you, you can try an alternative if the `reverse()` method is not made available to you or you are not allowed to use it.

1. You can create an empty string called `reversed`.
2. To iterate through the `string` that was provided and for each `character` in that `string`, you are going to take that `character` and add it to the start of `reversed`
3. Then you are going to return the variable `reversed`.

So you are taking each `character` out of the original string and sticking into the new one, one by one.

```
function reverse(string) {
  let reversed = '';
}
```

So I have declared a temporary variable called `reversed` and assigned it an empty string. This is the temporary variable I have assembled over time as I iterate through the `string` variable.

Now I need a `for` loop, but instead of a classic `for` loop I am going to use the ES2015 `for...of` loop.

```
function reverse(string) {
  let reversed = '';
  for (let character of string) {

  }
}
```

Notice the use of the `let` variable identifier? Its because I am going to reassign `reversed` like so:

```
function reverse(string) {
  let reversed = '';
  for (let character of string) {
    reversed = character + reversed;
  }
}
```

Lastly, as outlined in step 3, I return the new assignment of `reversed`.

```
function reverse(string) {
  let reversed = '';
  for (let character of string) {
    reversed = character + reversed;
  }
  return reversed;
}
```

So I am taking a temporary variable that is redeclared every single time through this loop of `character`. Then I say `of` and the iterable object that I want to iterate through, in this case, all the characters of the `string`.

So I will iterate through each `character`, one by one and then set each `character` equal to temporary variable of `character` and then I take that `character` and add it on to the start of `string` `reversed` and after the entire loop I `return` the `string` `reversed`.

You can use this in place of the classic for loop just keep in mind you will not be able to use this syntax if you are required to iterate through every third element. In such a case, you have to use the classic `for` loop.