# How to reverse a string using only one variable

Tags: javascript, algorithm

How to reverse string using next conditions:

1) if string isn't parameter of function,

2) if string is place in global scope,

3) use loop like for, while,

4) can add one variable

Note: Can't use method .join, .split, .reverse and so on...
If it possible and not so hard for you make explain your solution, very grateful !

---

#### In other words, this is what you got:

```
 let s = 'any string';
 let p; // feel free to use at your discretion

 // your code here. No further variables, no functions and no built-ins
 // should console.log the reversed string
```

---

I'm understand that my solution is very close to my desire (conditions), but i can't generate other solution.

```js
function convers(s){ //parameter 
 var str = "";//empty string for new converted string
 for(var i = s.length-1; i >= 0; i--)//loop decremebtation that count from end of string
 str+=s[i];//store result and assignments to str
 return str;// declare result 
}
console.log(convers("abcdef"));
```

I looked this source:
 [javascript reverse string algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41582256/javascript-reverse-string-algorithm)

[Is there a faster Reverse String Algorithm for JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48174796/is-there-a-faster-reverse-string-algorithm-for-javascript) - but it is useless for me, sorry.

I'm sorry if my explanation is not clear enough. Sorry for my English, I'm beginner here :))))

Comment: *but i can't generate other solution.* What does this mean? Which part isn't working?

Comment: Why do you think the answer can be improved?

Comment: @gurvinder I think by *solution* he means *algorithm*

Comment: This smells of do my homework because I do not know what to do.

Comment: This looks like a surprisingly good homework/interview question because of conditions 1 (which sorts out recursions) and especially 4

Comment: @Maxim Gordiyenko very nice question

Comment: @Maxim, I edited your question to make the point clear.

Comment: As you mentioned above it is really interview question.  All part of function work good, but what I did mean when said "I can't generate other solution" it means I couldn't imagine  other solution like below.  Interviewer said me that my solution isn't clear enough.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a new variable for the reverted string and use the length property for iterating.

```js
var string = 'abcdef',
    reverse = '';

while (reverse.length !== string.length) {
    reverse += string[string.length - 1 - reverse.length];
}
string = reverse;

console.log(string);
```

A bit shorter.

```js
var string = 'abcdef',
    reverse = '';

while (reverse.length !== string.length) {
    reverse = string[reverse.length] + reverse;
}
string = reverse;

console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below condition I hope it will help you

> 1) if string isn't parameter of function

```js
function convers(s){ //parameter 
s = s.toString();
 var str = "";//empty string for new converted string
 for(var i = s.length-1; i >= 0; i--)//loop decremebtation that count from end of string
 str+=s[i];//store result and assignments to str
 return str;// declare result 
}
console.log(convers(132));
```

> 2) if string is place in global scope

```js
function convers(){ //parameter 

 var str = "";//empty string for new converted string
 for(var i = dd.length-1; i >= 0; i--)//loop decremebtation that count from end of string
 str+=dd[i];//store result and assignments to str
 return str;// declare result 
}
var dd ="123";
console.log(convers());
```

> 3)  can add one variable

```js
function convers(s,dd){ //parameter 
 var str = "";//empty string for new converted string
 for(var i = s.length-1; i >= 0; i--)//loop decremebtation that count from end of string
 str+=s[i];//store result and assignments to str
 return str +dd;// declare result 
}
    function CallConvers(){
    var dd = "ADD";
    console.log(convers("abcdef",dd));
    }
    CallConvers();
```

Comment: `3) can add one variable` - you've got two (`str` and `i`)

Comment: please check now

Comment: Good third solutions, but if possible to declare just one variable it can be either global or local scope. Really I don't understand this solution, I deleted second parameter and nothing changed.

Comment: @MaximGordiyenko Please check 3rd solution